# why does input.value is returning undefined when call it in alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text input
and I want to alert the input.value after press enter

so I have made this code
HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="food">
```

js :

```
$('#food').on('keypress',function(e) {
 if(e.which == 13) {
    const food = $('#food').value;
    alert(food);
 }
});
```

in the alert, it's showing `undefined`.
in addition, there is no console error in the console

Comment: because you're using jquery ... in jquery it's `.val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `val()` method to get the value of the input in jquery

```
$('#food').val()
```

`value` is used in vanilla JS, not in jquery.

```js
$('#food').on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    const food = $('#food').val();
    console.log(food);
    // alert( food );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="food">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a function on jQuery to get that value.

```
$('#food').val();

$('#food').attr('value');
```

Comment: whats the attr does?

Comment: the attr function let you query some attribute from the element, like the value, also can query id, name, class, and more

Answer (score 0):

It is not `const food =  $("#food").value` but `const food = $("#food").val()`

Answer (score 0):

in jquery you should use .val() to get the value of the field insted of .value

```
`const food = $('#food').val();`
```